# MATLAB Parallel Parfor Memory Usage Interrogation

Tags: matlab, memory-management, parallel-processing

I am new here for asking questions though I have found solutions to many problems here before.

This particular problem I cannot seem to find an answer for so I though I would join up and ask.

I am using the Parallel computing toolbox to run multiple simulations at once, the code I am developing is to be deployed on a single core so there is no need for converting the algorithm to parallel.

The data structures being created by each of the simulations are large, and running 8 simulations at once is using all of the available RAM in my machine (4GB).

I am currently looking at reducing the memory used by each simulation, and was wondering if anybody knew how to get memory usage info from each of the instances of the function.

So far I have been calling:

```
parfor i=1:8
   [IR(:, i) Data(i)] =   feval(F, NX, NY(i), SR, NS, i);
end
```

And inside function F

```
[usr, sys] = memory;
format short eng;
TEST.Mem = usr.MemUsedMATLAB;
```

But this understandably is returning the memory being used by all 8 instances of F.

I would like to get the information from each instance of F.

Note: The data structure TEST is returned as Data to the top level function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "the memory used by all 8 instances of F" and "information from each instance of F" - your PARFOR loop is capturing each return from F in a separate element of the result, so that is "each instance".

Comment: Hi, While F is running it creates several large matrices, that depend on the input arguments when it is called, these are then used to obtain the result which is returned,

Comment: ** These matrices are then destroyed, but it is the memory being used while the function is running that I want to know

Comment: I'm still confused - "Data(i)" contains the memory information about the ith run of F, correct? If so, what more do you want to know?

Comment: Yes, Data(i) contains the information returned by `usr.MemUsedMATLAB` but this is the same whether the matrices (3 of them) are 1,000 points or 1,000,000 points.  Hence I have drawn the conclusion that the call is returning the memory being used in total by MATLAB, which is all instances of F as they are running in parallel.

Comment: As these 3 matrices are the dominant memory users in the function, for now I can use `TEST.Var = whos('p1','p2');` And look at the returned structures to get the memory size of the large matrices, though I would still like to find a tidier way of finding a complete memory usage for each separate simulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the matlab profiler to get a hint at the memory usage:

```
% start profiler
profile -memory on;

% start your simulation
my_sim();


% look at profiler results
profile viewer
```